# Sending money from India to USA (INR to USD)

Tags: india, money-transfer, money-order

I am an independent researcher from India and want to publish my dissertation in a US based publishing organization.The cost for publication is US$ 25, which they accept only via money order or check. I only own a saving account in an Indian bank. So what are my options here?

I contacted Western Union regarding this, but they said that they can't issue money order in my situation as I am not sending money to blood relative or for educational purpose.

Comment: Have you considered getting a USD check drawn on an Indian commercial bank 6which will probably offer that service) an mailing it to the publisher?

Comment: Are you confident this is a legit publisher?  I'm surprised they wouldn't offer credit card or similar as a method of payment.

Comment: Yes it is a legit publisher. Their policy says that they can only accept publication fee via money order or check.

Answer (score 1):

Do an semi-online transfer. I had a similar situation where i had to transfer 5K USD to a commercial entity.

You can request the publisher to give you their bank account details. You will need the SWIFT code of the bank( SWIFT code is a international code that each bank gets to transfer money)

You will need bank account number, account name, bank address, address of the publisher.

Then just walk into your bank with the above details. Note that you will have to visit a branch in your city that allows forex transfers. They will give you a set of forms to fill up. The above details will be needed to fill up these forms

In addition to the above, you will be asked to fill up a purpose code maintained by RBI.  This code is used by RBI to understand the reason why you are transferring the money. The bank will provide you with a sheet which will have these codes and explanation of these codes. Read through the codes and in case of any questions ask the bank officials to help

Tip: If you have accounts with any private sector banks, please approach them. Public sector banks will give you tough time

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

> The cost for publication is US$ 25, which they accept only via money order or check. I only own a saving account in an Indian bank.

India does not have International Money Order to US. If check's are fine, walk into your Branch and request for a US Dollar Banks Check. They should be able to arrange for one, there are fees associated with this. You can then mail this out to the US Organization.